# How can I hide the decoration of maximized windows?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, window-buttons

I just added the Window Buttons applet to my panel, but it seems that the **Hide Compiz decorations for maximized windows** feature no longer works after my upgrade to Natty. Is there another way to achieve the same effect in **Compiz**?

Comment: go into Compiz preference and check if the hide compiz decoration for maximized windows is in the block list.  if it is, move it to the right side.... if it isn't not in the block list and it's simply no longer working... well, hopefully someone else can answer.

Comment: What do you mean by, in the block list?

Comment: I posted an answer, it's not exactly what I wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it with compiz

- Install compiz config settings manager

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

  - Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
- In CCSM select window decorations
- Change decoration windows from `any` to `!(state=maxhorz and state=maxvert)`

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't done with Compiz, it is along the lines of what I was aiming for.

- Install **Maximus**:

  `sudo apt-get install maximus`
- Add it as a start-up application

[image]

- Log-out, log-in.