# Configure Compiz without CCSM

Tags: compiz, ccsm

Is there a way to edit Compiz settings in a config file or `gconf`/`dconf`?

Please provide an example configuration being done in CCSM and the alternative method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there are the standard tools:

- `gconf-editor` (GUI)
- `gconftool` / `gconftool-2` (CLI)
- `dconf-editor` (GUI)

All my compiz settings are in gconf under `/apps/compiz-1`

For you exact example:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string '/apps/compiz-1/plugins/decor/screen0/options/decoration_match' '!state=maxvert'
```

Comment: Can you give an example instruction for doing [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39871/how-can-i-hide-the-decoration-of-maximized-windows/41675#41675) configuration using the tools you mentioned?

Comment: Nice find on the example Oli +1 for beating me on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

### `dbus`

Example:

Set to single monitor:

`dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/core/screen0/hsize org.freedesktop.compiz.set int32:8
xrandr -s 1`

set to dual monitor:

`dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/core/screen0/hsize org.freedesktop.compiz.set int32:4
xrandr -s 0`

You can read more on the [compiz dbus wiki page](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus).

### Manual

See:

```
~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1/
/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1/
```

There are files named `%gconf.xml` in these directories for all the settings.

Comment: `dbus` example doesn't have much to do with Compiz configuration, does it? By the way, I need to chat with you regarding another answer.

Comment: see the link :-)